# What is cross domain web service calls with jquery?

Tags: jquery, web-services, cross-domain

I know that cross domain web service calls are restricted by default using Javascript including jQuery.

While this is true, I have the following scenario;

An ASPX page with jQuery hosted on http:localhost:9999 calling a web service which is hosted on http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:8888

According to the above, the jQuery will be doing a cross domain web service call. Why is it so that it is still working all good..? I am not receiving any errors.

I ask this question because in real scenario both the servers hosting ASPX page and the web service will be completely different and I am not sure whether this is going to work by default.

Note: I am not using JSONP or any other utilities to have this cross domain calls function properly.

I was thinking of implementing an ASPX page (as a web service caller page) which is solely for calling the web service. This is to circumvent the cross domain call error.

Please shed some light if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: A server can permit cross domain requests by emitting the appropriate CORS headers that tell the browser it's OK to access this server.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible the web service you are accessing has implemented Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) to specifically permit this.

Comment: This seems like a comment, not an answer and it's the contents of a comment that was already made 10 minutes ago.

Comment: Well, the question was "Why is it so that it is still working all good..?" so I disagree that my answer should have been a comment since it directly answered the question.  I do see we posted the same thing at the same time though.

Comment: Guys, just an insight (you may already know this), but I just happened to find that IE is more lenient on this than other browsers. I tested it with other browsers and it appears to be not working.. Thanks for your valuable knowledge sharing though..

Comment: It is possible to disable it in IE.